# how to find all solution for this pde

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

> lets $f(r,x)$ a function integrable and diferrentiable, and define
>
> $$\begin{align}L(r)&=\int_0^r\sqrt{1+\left[f_x(r,x)\right]^2}dx\\
> A(r)&=\int_0^rf(r,x)dx\end{align}$$
>
> find all $f(r,x)$ such that $L(r)=\frac{d}{dr}A(r)$

i get that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^r\sqrt{1+\left[f_x(r,x)\right]^2}dx&=\frac{d}{dr}\int_0^rf(r,x)dx\\
\int_0^r\sqrt{1+\left[f_x(r,x)\right]^2}dx&=f(r,r)+\int_0^rf_r(r,x)dx
\end{align}$$

by trial and error i find that $f(r,x)=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$, but i dont know how to solve or proof that its unique solution, how to solve this?

Comment: To rephrase this in more geometrical terms: You've got a family of curves parametrised by $r$, and you know that the area under the curve, $A$, is related to the arc length of the curve, $L$, through $L = A'$. In this context, especially since you suspect that the answer to the question for which curve the above is true is 'a circle', I'm thinking of the isoperimetric inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality), which relates the area enclosed by a curve to the length of that curve, and which is only an equality for circles. Just a thought!